# Alternate row color of a table which only displays even items

Tags: css, jsp, jstl, el

I am using JSTL and displaying the data in two tables side by side. To do that I am checking for even and odd and displaying odd list in one table and even in another.

Now for the table which has even records, I want to color the alternate row white and black. Can you let me know how I can do that?

I tried JavaScript as well to get the ID of the table and then assigning the color but it's not working.

```html
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
    <tr>
        <td width="50%">
            <!-- Table on left side -->
            <table id="tabbed" width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Id</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Description</th>
                        <th>Disp Ind</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <c:forEach items="${dynaItemGroupDetailListForm.map.itemsList}" var="item" varStatus="rowstatus">
                    <tr>
                        <c:choose>
                            <c:when test="${rowstatus.count % 2 == 1}">
                                <td><c:out value="${item.itemRefId}" /></td>
                                <td><c:out value="${item.itemNm}" /></td>
                                <td><c:out value="${item.itemDesc}" /></td>
                                <td><c:out value="${item.itemDisplayInd}" /></td>
                            </c:when>
                        </c:choose>
                    </tr>
                </c:forEach>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td width="50%">
            <!-- Table on right side -->
            <table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1">
                <tr class="even">
                    <th>Id</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th>Disp Ind</th>
                </tr>
                <c:forEach items="${dynaItemGroupDetailListForm.map.itemsList}" var="item" varStatus="rowstatus">
                    <tr>
                        <c:choose>
                            <c:when test="${rowstatus.count % 2 == 0}">
                                <td><c:out value="${item.itemRefId}" /></td>
                                <td><c:out value="${item.itemNm}" /></td>
                                <td><c:out value="${item.itemDesc}" /></td>
                                <td><c:out value="${item.itemDisplayInd}" /></td>
                            </c:when>
                        </c:choose>
                    </tr>
                </c:forEach>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

> *Now for the table which has even records, I want to color the alternate row white and black.*

So, that table (the second table, which is on the right side) contains rows 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, etc and you want to color 2, 6, 10, etc white and 4, 8, 12, etc black.

In other words, if `count % 4 == 0`, then it should be black, else it should be white. This is best to be done by setting the `<tr class>` classname with a conditional operator `?:` in the EL experssion.

So, the following should do:

```html
<c:forEach items="${dynaItemGroupDetailListForm.map.itemsList}" var="item" varStatus="rowstatus">
    <c:if test="${rowstatus.count % 2 == 0}">
        <tr class="${rowstatus.count % 4 == 0 ? 'table2even' : 'table2odd'}">
            <td><c:out value="${item.itemRefId}" /></td>
            <td><c:out value="${item.itemNm}" /></td>
            <td><c:out value="${item.itemDesc}" /></td>
            <td><c:out value="${item.itemDisplayInd}" /></td>
        </tr>
    </c:if>
</c:forEach>
```

with this CSS:

```css
.table2odd {
    background: white;
}

.table2even {
    background: black;
}
```

Note that I replaced the clumsy `<c:choose><c:when>` by a simple `<c:if>` and fixed its illogical place as well (your original attempt would render empty `<tr>` elements which is invalid).

Comment: Thanks for you reply. As you mentioned, I made the changes and tried but still its not working. All the rows in the table on right hand side are with the same color. Any suggestions what might be wrong ?

Comment: 'The styling i defined is : <style type="text/css">

  tr.table2even  {
    background-color: white;
}

  tr.table2odd  {
    background-color: black;
}


</style>'